# Manage Usernames and passwords for industrial company

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Username & Password Database Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026230/username-password-database-design)

I'm designing a Management Information System for Industrial Company , which has different types of users ( employees , customers , suppliers ) . every type of them is single entity ( table ) when I'm designing the database using ( MS-Access ) .
and I have to give each single one of them its own unique Username , How can I do that ?

Comment: Industrial company? Access? Sir, no.

Comment: Please, hire someone to do this for you. Username, password, personal details storage and security is a serious business. You can be in serious legal trouble if you don't execute it correctly.

Comment: in fact it's project for my college , nothing Pro here !

Comment: Wadda7 please don't ask the same question in a new post.

Comment: Sounds liek you're asking people to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use table inheritance - i.e. have an Entity table that stores core info like user ID, username, password etc. and then have entity type tables (supplier, customer etc.) to store the other information that foreign key onto your entity table.

Comment: Exactly.  Supertype is entity, Subtype are customers, suppliers, employees, directors etc.

Comment: Shall I Connect Entity_ID to X_ID ( X = Supplier , Customer , Employee .. etc ) ? One-To-One relationship ?

Answer (score -1):

This is one option... I'm guess Access can handle FK.

```
user
----
id
username
password
employeeid fk references employee.id
customerid fk references customer.id
supplierid fk references supplier.id

employee
--------
id
<other employee specific columns>

customer
--------
id
<other customer specific columns>

supplier
--------
id
<other supplier specific columns>
```